# How to refresh the fields in a popup for Operations Dashboard?

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

I have a hosted feature layer that I had added to an Operations Dashboard.

Then I removed 3 fields.

Within the map viewer, when I click on a point, the popup displays correctly with the 3 fields removed.

Within the operations dashboard map, when I click on a point, the popup still displays the old fields.
[image]

How do I refresh the Operation Dashboard with the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to re-create the hosted feature layer, rebuild the web map and use the new web map in the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you've saved the pop-up configuration change to the webmap (or layer item if applicable), then after refreshing the dashboard it *should* display correctly in the pop-up of the dashboard map.

Modifications to the schema of the layer (e.g., deleting three fields) could cause issues for the dashboard, if this is what you are doing.

In either case, I suggest you work with Esri Support to resolve the problem if it persists.

Comment: I agree that this is expected behavior. After talking with other Operation Dashboard users, it appears this is a known issue and rebuilding the dashboard is the typical workaround.